# Delphi 5 + BDE + TStoredProc + Oacle + Thread

Tags: multithreading, oracle, delphi, bde

i'm trying to develop a application that runs a stored procedure in a background mode.

1 - If i run in the mains thread, it's OK, it's lock the screen.

2 - If i put the stpGen.ExecProc; in a thread, it's runs OK, but it's lock the mains thread too.

is there a option to run TStoredProc in a thread and don't lock the main thread?

Code:

```
type
   TStoredProcSegundoPlano = class(TThread)
   private
      stpGen: TStoredProc;
      excErro: Exception;
   protected
      procedure Execute; override;
   public
      constructor Create(const stpGen: TStoredProc; const blnAutoFree, blnAutoStart: Boolean);
      property Erro: Exception read excErro;
   end;

implementation

{ TStoredProcSegundoPlano }

constructor TStoredProcSegundoPlano.Create(const stpGen: TStoredProc;
  const blnAutoFree, blnAutoStart: Boolean);
begin
   inherited Create(True);
   Self.excErro := nil;
   Self.stpGen := stpGen;
   if blnAutoFree then
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
   if blnAutoStart then
      Resume;
end;

procedure TStoredProcSegundoPlano.Execute;
begin
   try
      try
         stpGen.ExecProc;
      except
         on E: Exception do
         begin
            excErro := AcquireExceptionObject;
         end;
      end;
   finally
      Terminate;
   end;
end;
```

so, i call this way:

```
TStoredProcSegundoPlano.Create(stpGen, True, True);
```

in this moment, the application is ok, but few seconds after, the maisn threads lock, i don't have any idea know to resolve this, it's possivel to run a TStoredProc un a background?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly you have some interaction going on between your main thread and worker thread, but we can't tell because we cannot see your code.

Comment: @JerryDodge I altered the question.

Comment: Thanks for editing, that makes it clear what your problem is. You're currently passing in a reference to the `TStoredProc` which defeats the purpose of using a thread. The `TStoredProc` should be created and used only within the thread its self, and pass in the statement which needs to be executed. As of now, although you're instructing it to execute from within the thread, the actual execution is being done from your main thread still. Also, we need to see how you're actually calling the thread (are you waiting for its response?)

Comment: ok, i undertand, i will change this and respond here, Thanks

Comment: @JerryDodge: what you are saying is incorrect. The StoredProc is surely executed from the secondary thread, the reald problem is that the database session/Connection itself must live in the same thread or else you will encounter problems. So all the OP must do, is create a new database connection from the Thread's execute method.

Comment: ok, this is true, but, i really like to resolve this, usin the same connection, i resolved this, crating other connection, but, creating other connection can limit the server connections limit license, so, i need to use the same connection, threre is a way to share the bde TDatabase/TSession whith other TDatabase/Session Component?

Comment: @Passella Unfortunately, one of the fundamental purposes of using a worker thread is that **all** the work is done from within that thread, self-contained. There should be nothing inside this thread that relies on anything outside the thread. That includes database connections (in fact some connection types like ADO it's impossible to re-use the same connection inside 2 different threads).

Comment: @whosrdaddy Indeed, that's what I essentially meant, is that the connection (and `TStoredProc`) are instantiated within the main thread, so when trying to use them from the worker thread, it's locking the main thread.

Comment: @JerryDodge so is impossible to execute a StoredProc in a thread ising a TDatabase/TSession created in the main thread?

Comment: the problem is in unit DBTables; 

function TStoredProc.GetCursor(GenHandle: Boolean): HDBICur;

Check(DbiQExec(StmtHandle, PCursor));

when the program reach this point, it's lock the main thread, but, this execution, is in the other thread

Comment: @Passella That's correct, the whole purpose of a thread is to encapsulate everything within, even if it means making a second instance of a database connection (especially the connection actually). Bear in mind that you presumably want to observe the response of that thread call, so that requires either waiting for the response in a loop (your UI won't be responsive in this case either, you'll have to force this) or blindly trigger this thread and let the thread trigger an event back to the calling thread. Either way, you shouldn't instantiate anything in one thread and feed it into the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59533/discussion-between-passella-and-jerry-dodge).

Comment: One thing you can also consider is using a connection pool. That will allow you to share the connection between the thread and the main application provided neither are using them at the same time. Every time you need a connection do you something like GetConnection; xxxxx; ReleaseConnection;